# Setting the seed for random forest with different number of mtry and trees

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, reproducible-research

Good morning, I am familiarizing with both machine learning and the caret packet to run some algorithms (random forest and support vector machine). I would like to run the random forest in parallel using the caret package and set the seeds for reproducible results. I am using 10-fold CV, with 11 mtry. Here is my code following the examples provided in https://valentinitnelav.github.io/satellite-image-classification-r/#random_forest. In addition, I am looping around the number of trees:

`

```
n_folds <- 10
set.seed(321)
folds <- createFolds(1:nrow(data_Train), k = n_folds)
seeds <- vector(mode = "list", length = n_folds + 1) 
for(i in 1:n_folds) seeds[[i]] <- sample.int(1000, n_folds)
seeds[n_folds + 1] <- sample.int(1000, 1) 
ctrl <- trainControl(summaryFunction = multiClassSummary,
                     method = "cv",
                     number = n_folds,
                     search = "grid",
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     savePredictions = TRUE,
                     index = folds,
                     seeds = seeds)

cl <- makeCluster(3/4 * detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)

modellist <- list()
for (ntree in c(100,200,300,400,500,1000,1500)){
  set.seed(321)
  model_rf <- caret::train(CLASS_NAME ~ . , method = "rf", data = data_Train,
                           importance = TRUE,
                           tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = seq(2,length(data_Train)-1,1)),
                           trControl = ctrl,
                           ntree = ntree)
  key <- toString(ntree)
  modellist[[key]] <- model_rf
}
```

`

My question is related to the line:

`for(i in 1:n_folds) seeds[[i]] <- sample.int(1000, n_folds)`

In my case, since I have 11 values for mtry and 7 different models for each value of ntree, should I set:

`for(i in 1:n_folds) seeds[[i]] <- sample.int(1000, 11*7)` ?

Could anybody clarify this point better?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: May I ask why you want to set multiple seeds?

Comment: From what I understood from the source I provided before and other questions on Stack Overflow, we use seeds to allow reproducible research for fitting the model at each iteration and to compare different types of models, which is what I am going to do. Also, from the caret help in r (help(trainControl)) it reports that seeds is "an optional set of integers that will be used to set the seed at each resampling iteration. This is useful when the models are run in parallel".

Comment: Sure, usually we use `set.seed()` once to fix the random generator; if you reproduce the code, the generator will produce the same random numbers again. When using parallelization, you might want to look into `parallel::clusterSetRNGStream(cl, iseed=seed)`, which also allows to set the seed only once. I admit I'm not using caret very much, but I would give it a shot to avoid tedious multiple seeding.